# How to Access Server Certificate information in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, certificate, nsurlconnection

For my application I have a trusted server certificate and I want to access the certificate information in my code. My purpose is to check whether the url hostname and the certificate hostname match or not. If they match, then I will make the connection, otherwise I will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

1. you use the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods `-connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:` and `-connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` to receive an authentication challenge in the *server trust* protection space. That's where you get the opportunity to inspect the certificate.
2. Don't just check that the hostname matches! Anyone could issue themselves with a certificate for any server, and there have even been certificates issued for `*.*.com` and similar wildcards. You need to decide whether you *trust* the identity that was issued with the certificate: that's why it's called server trust authentication.

> how can I trust the identity that was issued with the certificate

You need to evaluate the server trust. What your *policy* is for trusting certificates is not something I'd like to predict, but how you use the API to evaluate the trust is covered in Apple's [Certificate, Key and Trust Services programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html).

> and how can I access some of the information within the certificate

The available APIs are documented in the [Certificate, Key and Trust Services reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157). Notice that there aren't many options on iOS for extracting data from the certificate - certainly not as many as there are on the Mac.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this field...I've used NSURLConnectionDelegate methods - connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: and -connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge. As you pointed out, how can I trust the identity that was issued with the certificate and how can I access some of the information within the certificate? thanks.